# Find the error in my proof - Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Show that $|2\cdot\ln \cos x + x^2|\leq \frac{\pi^3}{48}$ for $|x|\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$ using Taylor's theorem.

**My proof:** Let $f(x)=\ln \cos x$ and write down the second-degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $0$ which is $$T_0(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Using Taylor's theorem and calculating $f'''(0)=0$ we get that $$\forall x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2):f(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+0\cdot f'''(\eta_x)$$ for some $\eta_x$ with $|\eta_x-0|\leq|x-0|$.

Hence: $$|2\cdot\ln \cos x + x^2|=0\;\forall x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\;\;(1)$$

which is very unlikely since we are asked to show the statement for $|x|\leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ but according to what I have it holds for arbitrary $|x|< \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $(1)$ also seems very unlikely to be true.

Comment: Taylor Theorem asserrts that $f(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{1}{3!}f'''(\eta_x)x^3$

Comment: @Tito Thanks, that's what's wrong then. Do you know how I can continue from there?

Comment: You need to find an upper bound for $|f'''|$ on the interval $\bigl[-\frac\pi 4,\frac\pi 4\bigr]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want just to the second degree, you can calculate the polynomial directly. You have 
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x},\ \ f''(x)=-\frac1{\cos^2x},\ \ f'''(x)=-\frac{2\sin x}{\cos^3x}. 
$$
As $$f(0)=0,\ \ f'(0)=0,\ \ f''(0)=-1.$$
This gives you have
$$
\ln(\cos x)=-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{2\sin \xi}{\cos^3\xi}\,\frac{x^3}6
$$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$. So 
$$
|2f(x)+x^2|=\frac{2|\sin\xi|}{|\cos\xi|^3}\,\frac{x^3}6.
$$
Because $|x|\leq\tfrac\pi4$, you have $|\xi|\leq\tfrac\pi4$ and so 
$$
\cos\xi\geq\frac1{\sqrt2},\ \ |\sin\xi|\leq\frac1{\sqrt2}.
$$
Then, when $|x|\leq\tfrac\pi4$, 
$$
|2f(x)+x^2|\leq\frac{2/\sqrt2}{(1/\sqrt2)^3}\,\frac{(\pi/4)^3}6=\frac46\,\frac{\pi^3}{4^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{96}<\frac {\pi^3}{48}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the problem is that we have to find the upper bound such that $|2f(x)+x^2|\leq \frac{\pi^3}{48}$ but $96=2\cdot 48$. Do you know how we can deal with that?

Comment: Yes, by noticing that $\frac1 {96}<\frac1 {48} $.

Comment: Oh thank you, that was a rather quick solution.